# How to bulk change the products price from one currency to another in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, currency

I have to change the regular price and sales price of all products(more than 10000) from USD to INR. Client wants all the price should be converted in INR by multiplying it to 64.72 (current dollar to inr rate). It was entered in USD during product creation. But now client insist to change into INR from everywhere

Note that, Change of original price in database is must, we are not using any currency converter tool to just show the end user using conversion tools.

Example
Suppose product price is 100 USD, now after bulk update it should be 6472.00 INR in database as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSV file with all your product with the new prices and import them into WooCommerce.  You want to select the "[Merge Products](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-csv-import-suite-importing-products/)" option so that if the products match via ID or SKU then they will be updated by the importing tool.